# How to add an update button to a PHP Generated Table

Tags: php

On my website, I am using a php code to display a table with information from my database. I am trying to add an update button so that users can update the "status" field for each row (in other words, an update button for each row, that when clicked, will update the "status" column for that row only). How can I do this? Here is my code:

```
    <?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "correspondence");
if (!$link){
die("Can not connect: " . mysqli_error());
}
mysqli_select_db($link, "correspondence");


$sql = "SELECT * FROM tracker WHERE department='N2'";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";  
                echo "<th>Tracking Number</th>";
                echo "<th>Subject</th>";
                echo "<th>Date Entered</th>";
                echo "<th>Originator</th>";
                echo "<th>Department</th>";
                echo "<th>Status</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['person_id'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['subject'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['date_entered'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['originator'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['department'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";     
                echo "</form>";
                echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";

        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Ajax will do the trick.

Comment: Should the status be toggled or are there more than two possible stati?

Comment: By *will update* do you mean **getting** the updated value of the "status" column  or **setting** it?

Comment: @Majid Fouladpour , setting it. For example, the users types "Document pending"in the status column of a row and clicks the "update" button. After refreshing the page, in that same box, it now says "Document Pending" .Then, the user can type "Complete" and click update. After refreshing, the "status" column for that row now says "Complete".

Comment: In `tracker` table, do you have primary key? How do you uniquely identify a record in this table?

Comment: @MajidFouladpour yes. I have a column titled "person_id" which has an auto increment of integer and is the primary key, which i used to uniquely identify each row.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the most simple solution

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "correspondence");

if (!$link)
{
        die("Can not connect: " . mysqli_error());
}

mysqli_select_db($link, "correspondence");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tracker WHERE department='N2'";


if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql))
{

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {
                echo "<table>";
                echo "<tr>";  
                echo "<th>Tracking Number</th>";
                echo "<th>Subject</th>";
                echo "<th>Date Entered</th>";
                echo "<th>Originator</th>";
                echo "<th>Department</th>";
                echo "<th>Status</th>";
                echo "<th></th>";
                echo "</tr>";
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['person_id'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['subject'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['date_entered'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['originator'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['department'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td><form method=\"post\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"$row['id']\">Update</input></form>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                }
        echo "</table>";

        mysqli_free_result($result);
        } 
                else
                {
                        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
                }
}
else
{
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

The row's ID is sent with the POST Request when you click the button.

(I'm assuming you're using autoincremented integer ID's or char UUID's)

You just need to check for it in the `$_POST[]` superglobal, update the row

```
UPDATE tracker
SET status='status'
WHERE id=ID
```

Comment: Received the error (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: Was missing a semicolon.

Comment: Now getting: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Correspondence\N2.php on line 100

Comment: line 100 is:                            echo "<td><form method=\"post\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"$row['id']\">Update</input></form>";

Answer (score 0):

OK, there is a no-js way of doing this which would not be elegant at all, and a cleaner solution if you make use of a library like jQuery to help with posting the request. I'd show the later.

Firstly we need to give each row an identifier. We also give the status `td` a `class` so we can easily bind a click event handler for it:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  echo "<tr data-id='{$row['person_id']}'>";
  ...
  echo "<td class='status'>{$row['status']}</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

The next part is binding a handler for click event on the status:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("table").on("click", "td.status", function() {
    var $td = $(this),
        old = $td.text(),
        frm = '<input type="text" id="status" value="'+old+'/>' +
              '<button onclick="post_update(this);">Update</button>';
    $td.html(frm);
  });
});
function post_update(b) {
  var $tr   = $(b).parents('tr'),
      state = $tr.find("input").val(),
      id    = $tr.data("id");
  $.post("update_state.php", {s: state, r: id}, function(resp) {
    if("err" in resp) {
      alert(resp.err);
      return false;
     }
     $("tr[data-id='" + resp.id + "'] td.state").html(resp.state);
  }, "json");
}
```

Finally, you need the following in `update_state.php`:

```
<?php
require('dbconfig.php'); // Put DB constants in a single place
$link = mysqli_connect(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS,DBNAME);
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);
$person_id = (int) $_POST['r'];
$new_state = $_POST['s'];
$query = "UPDATE `tracker` SET `state` = ? WHERE `person_id` = ? LIMIT 1";
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'si', $new_state, $person_id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$n = mysqli_affected_rows($link);
if($n === 1) {
  $resp = ['id'=>$person_id, 'state'=>$new_state];
} else {
  $resp = ['err' => "No record updated. Either the person with id $person_id does not exist, or the original state was the same as the new one"];
}
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
die(json_encode($resp));
?>
```